# Javascript Alert Written To The Top Of Rendered HTML

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I am trying to display an alert for IE browsers earlier than IE8.  I am using a javascript alert in my code behind.  However, this alert gets written to the top of the rendered HTML so that on postback the DOCTYPE declaration is no longer the first line of HTML and this causes IE8 to switch into Quirks mode.  How can I fix this?

Any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use Response.Write to alert the user; instead use something like this:

```
function alertOldBrowser()
{
    alert('Your browser is IE <8 ');
}
```

And on code behind, call this function as so:

```
if(browserIsOld)
{
   Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alertOldBrowser();", true);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to call RegisterStartupScript in your code behind:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asz8zsxy.aspx